# Eclipse javadoc font display is not normal

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I found some Eclipse issues.
Some of my information:

```
System          : Windows 10 Enterprise 1703( OS Internal version 15063.483)
Eclipse version : eclipse-jee-2019-03-M1、eclipse-jee-2018-12-R(Because they all have the same problem)
Jdk version     : JDK8
Eclipse Font setting : Consolas
```

My Eclipse is almost just downloaded, and no plugins are installed.The lower version does not have this problem.

the javadoc:

```
   /**
    * 申请转让
    * @param userId
    * @param transferId 债权Id
    * @param transferValue 转让价格
    */
```

Problem Screenshot here:

[image]

In line 103, I used Chinese to comment, but the font seems to be indented to the left. And only appears in the second line of javadoc. But if you type a letter, it will return to normal.

Normal Screenshot here:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

other font setting(Microsoft Yahei):

[image]

It seems normal after setting up Microsoft Yahei.

Comment: Please add the relevant characters as text to your question and say which languages with which writing direction are affected. Have you checked whether this has already been reported to Eclipse?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, add a description, the font setting is Consolas. Not reported yet, I am planning to confirm the issue before reporting.

Comment: Please add this Chinese characters as text so it is possible for others to reproduce this issue. Do you know if the characters are included in Consolas or displayed via another font?

Comment: Sounds similar to https://bugs.eclipse.org/446414